# Javascript Exit from child function

Tags: javascript, function, parent

i have group of bind's, which gets trigger inside a function from before and after the code. like following:

```
function global() {
    before(); // call all before binds here

    //... mainFunction code...

    after(); // call all after binds here 
}
```

if one of functions inside `before();` callback wants to exit or stop the `global()` from running further, how can i stop it, without checking the return values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this without checking the value [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)ed, is to raise an exception by [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)ing an [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

```
function before() {
    throw new Error('Ending execution');
}
function after() {
    console.log('Have you met Ted?');
}
function global() {
    before();
    // never reaches here
    after();
}
global(); // Error: Ending execution
console.log('foo'); // not executed
```

If you have `global` invoked somewhere and want any code following it's invocation to continue being executed, you'll need to wrap it with a [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), for example

```
function global() {
    try {
        before();
        // never reaches here
        after();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e); // log error. Leave this block empty for no action
    }
}
global(); // Error logged
console.log('bar'); // still executed
```

Comment: wouldn't that will stop other functions too? other functions from ouside global();

Comment: Other functions in series, yes. I'll edit for a solution to that

Comment: @Basit further, I used `global` as I copied your example, but you're likely to run into conflict issues if you actually put something called `global` in the global namespace so try to choose different names / write modular code.